# Is there a way to add a custom html template to Javadoc which can be used with JAvadoc.exe?

Tags: java, html, templates, javadoc

Is it possible to add a custom HTML template to javadoc auto-generator. 
I am looking for a way to integrate a custom HTMl/CSS template to my javadocs. For example, a template which gives a header to my javadoc with the application name, etc.
Currently I have to change the javadoc html post-generation.
Let me clarify again that i am talking about HTMl template not the Javadoc templates (which contains variables with "@" ).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [subclass the standard Doclet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html) to customize the output however you like.

Comment: thanks but Doclets don’t solve the exact problem that i am facing but some searches with keyword doclet led me to doclet.com which contains a decent list of things. thanks for the quick answer.